# How to unit test a function, which just calls other functions?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

There is a function in my codebase (legacy), which has:

```
function test()
{
 method1("#input a")
 method2("test")
 method3(1,2)
}
```

given the fact it calls other `methods`, how one will write a good unit testing for these sort of functions?

Comment: my point is that for such function, no unit test is needed, just test the internal methods is enough.

Comment: Is it really enough? Changing the order of call inside this function will change its behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

First, I do not think such a behavior as you described even need to have a unit test.
BUT, If you really need to check if the methods are called with specific parameters (or even any parameters). 
There is a way you could do that, you could use a mocking framework like ShortifyPunit:
https://github.com/danrevah/ShortifyPunit

Follow this steps:

1. Make sure the methods attached to an object you can mock
2. Inject a mocked object to your class and stub the methods
3. You could verify() the methods were called with specific parameters

For example if your class is using the dependency injection, which is crucial for unit testing like the following class:

```
class SomeClass {

    private $obj;

    public function __construct($obj) {
        $this->obj = $obj;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        $this->obj->method1("#input a")
        $this->obj->method2("test")
        $this->obj->method3(1,2)
    }
}
```

You could write a unit test as follows:

```
public function testMethodCalled()
{
    $mockedObj = ShortifyPunit::mock('object');

    $class = new SomeClass($mockedObj);

    // Stub the methods so you could verify they were called
    ShortifyPunit::when($mockedObj)->method1(anything())->returns(1);
    ShortifyPunit::when($mockedObj)->method2(anything())->returns(2);
    ShortifyPunit::when($mockedObj)->method3(anything(), anything())->returns(3);

    $class->test(); // run test() method

    // Verify it was called
    $this->assertTrue(ShortifyPunit::verify($mockedObj)->method1(anything())->calledTimes(1));
    $this->assertTrue(ShortifyPunit::verify($mockedObj)->method2(anything())->calledTimes(1));
    $this->assertTrue(ShortifyPunit::verify($mockedObj)->method3(anything(), anything())->calledTimes(1));
}
```

Comment: In general your advice is good but at least in JS you could mock the functions directly without using an object.

Answer (score 4):

> given the fact it calls other `methods` (…)

It doesn't matter what it calls. From consumer (caller) point of view the **end result** is important. You always test the end result. The fact that some other methods are called is *irrelevant implementation detail* (in most cases).

I suggest simple exercise - inline `method1`, `method2` and `method3` bodies into `test` method. Would you have problems identifying what to test?

You want to test the public contract, or observable behavior - the end result of method call visible for someone calling it (many different actors might call your method - other parts of program, unit test or system user; each should experience the same *observable behavior*).

Now, back to the "end result"/"method's observable behavior" which was mentioned several times. It can be one of three things:

- returned value (your method doesn't do that)
- call to third party components (your method might be doing that)
- change in system's internal state (your method seem to be doing that)

You need to identify the end result and test against it.

Answer (score 0):

This is very good question and I too struggled with it for a long time. In your case you have a function `test` which you want to test , but the function has dependencies — `method1-3`. 
There are basically two ways —

1. Keep the code as is and simply test the `test` function.
2. Pass dependencies as params —

Example —

```
function test(method1, method2, method3) {
 method1("#input a")
 method2("test")
 method3(1,2)
}
```

The second approach would give you the flexibility to mock the methods 1, 2 & 3.

It could also be a mix of case one and two, where some methods are directly used from the global scope and some are passed as params.

The only problem now is to understand when to use what. Here are some tips —

**For case one**

1. The dependencies are simple synchronous functions. In JS, async functions generally do some IO related work or sometime very expensive computations, both of which should not come in the way of testing your `test` function.
2. It takes input params and return an output.
3. They do NOT mutate any state or dispatch any event, anywhere in the application.

For all other cases, you would want to pass the dependencies as params. For example — in this case, it looks like `method1` and `method2` are doing some DOM operations, which means they should be injected and mocked where as `method3` looks pretty simple and can be used from the global scope.

```
function (d) {
  d.method1("#input a")
  d.method2("test")
  method3(1,2)
}
```

*If the dependencies become too many, you can pass an object containing the all dependencies.*